# Do mobile phones have a Server : Port Scheme ?

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I am new to mobile phone programming, find networking very interesting, and have this question:

- Does a phone running Windows Mobile or other OS's have Server:Port scheme, and what are the ports?

Using a PC to demonstrate, there are many ports (restricted and established). The below is the Server : Port scheme:

```
  Server  : (port example)    WebServer    80
```

So to use a TCPListener on a PC, I can use any port as long as it is not restricted and establsihed) to listen to an incoming TcpClient .

- How do I use a TCPListener and Which portNo I need to use to listen incoming TcpClient from the other end in Net Compact Framework?

Thanks.